# Count my totals up - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a "orders" table that holds the totals in each row for every order in my shop. I need to count all my totals from every single row to get a grand total. How would I set up my query in Laravel?

My Orders Table:

[image: My Orders Table]

My function:

```html
   public function index() {

        // Get all the orders in DB
        $orders = Order::all();

        // THAT DOESNT WORK, it just counts the rows
        $count_total = DB::table('orders')->select('count(total)')->count();
        dd($count_total); 

        // Get all the carts in DB
        $carts = Cart::all();


        return view('admin.pages.index', compact('orders', 'carts', 'count_products'));
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use Eloquent way, by doing this you can get total sum of column.

```
$total = Orders::sum('total');
echo "<pre>";
  print_r($total);
echo "<pre>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [`sum()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#aggregates) aggrigate method:

```
$count_total = DB::table('orders')->sum('total');
```

Comment: Wow, it was that easy, Thanks!